# TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON at JSON.stringify

Tags: javascript, angularjs

On POST request, when I do `angular.toJson` on the payload, i am getting this error.

> angular.js:12609 TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
>       at JSON.stringify ()
>       at Object.db [as toJson] (http://localhost:8080/adminconsole/lib/bower_components/angular/angular.modified.min.js?_1553818615062:15:433)

Any idea what is the reason?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello Parveen, Welcome to stackoverflow. Could you please post the code relevant to your question so other people can understand more about your problem ?

Comment: please attach code and response as well.

Answer (score -1):

JavaScript structures that include circular references can't be serialized with a"plain" JSON.stringify. Example:

Copy
`a = { name: 'Groucho' };
b = { name: 'Harpo', sibling: a };
a.sibling = b;`

Doing a JSON.stringify(a) will throw an error:

Copy
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

There is not much you can do about that except specifying a custom serializer function that detects and cleans up circular references. There are existing solutions so you do not need to think of one yourself, like https://github.com/WebReflection/circular-json

For the above structure you will then get the following.

Copy
`{"name":"Groucho","sibling":{"name":"Harpo","sibling":"[Circular ~]"}}`

Note how [Circular ~] shows the path to the referenced object. In more deeply nested structures, you would see something like [Circular ~.rows.1].